# Twitter API get streaming data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am exploring the Twitter streaming API and have gone through various documents and examples, but I don't know where to start.
I could not find a beginners tutorial.

Most of the examples use a username and password - are these the Twitter account username and password?

I appreciate if someone can list down the steps to follow.

I am working in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter have deprecated `API v1.0` which was using only username of any person to get tweets.

So you have to use `API v1.1`. Please go through following links, you will get much information about creating API.

[Simple Tweets](https://github.com/jnicol/tweet-php)

[Advance with layout](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/)

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to get all tweets on twitter rather then for particular user?

Comment: @user2129623 You can get all tweets of particular user or all tweets on user's timeline, by calling api like `user_timeline` and `home_timeline`.

Comment: thanks but. I did not mean that. I wanted to know in place of getting tweets for any user, Can I get tweets for any group or all tweets taken place on twitter on particularDay?

Comment: @user2129623 Sorry, but I also don't know much about twitter API. But you can go through links I have given, you might bet all the details.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not get all tweets. This is called the firehose and costs several million dollars a year. Twitter only sells that to a few partners.